# Get Youtube username without API PHP

Tags: php, youtube

How do you retrieve the username of someone on Youtube who is using your application with PHP? I'd prefer to do this without the API but if needs be point me in the right direction because i don't know what to download , I've visited the google developers site / place already.

I found some code from 2009 but it was to retrieve usernames from a youtube video and it didn't work. I tried reading the contents of page with the `fopen()` and `file_get_contents()` but it always appears as if I'm not signed in whereas I am signed in via FireFox.

Don't know if this makes a difference but I was running this on EasyPHP via localhost

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can't, by design. You do not have their session cookie server-side where you're using `fread`. Youtube determines whether you are or are not signed in based on that session cookie, and you do not have one on your server.

If you want their YouTube user name, use a client-side API in JavaScript or simply ask them for it with a text input field. It is impossible to find it server-side, as it should be. Your server has no business finding out my Youtube username without my express permission and interaction.

Comment: So there's no way to do this (apart from the above ) even with the Youtube API itself ?

Comment: No, not unless you prompt them for their credentials. You have no information on the user tying them to Youtube, there is nothing to supply Youtube via an API to return a username. What are you going to do, ask "what is the username for this IP address?" That might return dozens of usernames or no usernames, and they might all be incorrect.

Comment: You should be very, very thankful that it isn't possible. It would be a massive security problem with the fundamental architecture of the Internet.

Comment: Any random server being able to somehow figure out my username for any *other* server? Do you not see why that's a problem? Servers aren't even able to figure out whether or not you have an account elsewhere, let alone the account name. Put it this way: I don't want your website to be able to tell whether or not I am a member of xxx-porn-site.com.

Comment: NO, nothing to do with spam, everything to do with security and privacy. Why in gods name would I want your server to be able to figure out my Youtube username? Maybe I post personal videos that I don't want you to see? Maybe I have accounts where I post anti-government diatribes that could get me killed in my home country? Maybe my password is the same on Youtube as it is for your site, and by figuring out my username you can steal my account? This stuff is fundamentally important, and you should obtain a basic grounding in it before you do any web development.